# ZXing.Net.Mobile scanner view could not be re-enalbed for Android in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, zxing

I use [ZXing.Net.Mobile](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) ZXingScannerView in a Xamarin.Forms application. Currently i'm targeting Android API 21+ and Windows Mobile 10. I'm enabling / disabling the scanner via IsScanning property. While it works ok for UWP app on both emulators and real device, this is not true for Android. 
On both an Android emulator and a real device, setting `IsScanning = true` does not reenable the camera stream.

I'm using code similar to this example:

*SomePage.xaml*

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    ...
    <StackLayout>
        <zxing:ZXingScannerView
            x:Name="zxing"
            Result="{Binding ScannerResult, Mode=TwoWay}"
            IsScanning="{Binding ScannerScanning}"
            ScanResultCommand="{Binding ScannedCommand}"/>
        <Button Text="ON" Command="{Binding ScannerOnCommand}"  />
        <Button Text="OFF" Command="{Binding ScannerOffCommand}"  />
    ...
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

*SomeViewModel.cs*

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    ....
    public bool ScannerScanning { get; set; }
    public Result ScannerResult { get; set; }

    public ICommand ScannedCommand => new Command(() => ExecuteScannedCommand());
    public ICommand ScannerOnCommand => new Command(() => ExecuteScannerOnCommand());
    public ICommand ScannerOffCommand => new Command(() => ExecuteScannerOffCommand());

    private async Task ExecuteScannedCommand()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine();
    }

    private void ExecuteScannerOnCommand()
    {
        ScannerScanning = true;
    }

    private void ExecuteScannerOffCommand()
    {
        ScannerScanning = false;
    }
    ...
}
```

What do i miss or it's a bug in ZXing.Net.Mobile?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I added some code to clarify my case

Comment: There are some setup required https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile.forms Have you done all required steps? IsScanning is used a little differently that you show. Can you provide sample project for us to make sure you did everything required and according to their guide?

Comment: @YuriS Thank you for your effort! Scanner view IsScanning does work in UWP app, but just don't in Android. If you want, you can create a very basic app according the instructions you've pointed to and adapt it to my simple example above.

Comment: I was able to reproduce what you describing. I also tested this on IOS and it doesn't work for me at ll, the app just crashes. On UWP it also didn't work for me to switch between IsScanning. I wouldn't use View, I would use Page. Go to page, scan and go back. Sorry couldn't help you more

Comment: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/231

Comment: @YuriS Thank you anyway. I'll try to debug and fix the zxing issue by my own when i find some free time.